# Leaflet Time-Slider plugin issue: map moves when sliding the time slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, jquery-ui-slider

I am using the [time-slider plugin](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) by Dennis Wilhelm to implement a time slider on my leaflet map. Everything worked perfectly except for one small issue. When I open the map in IE (i'm using IE version 11.0.31), the map moves when I slide the timer slider. However, I don't have the problem with Chrome. It seems to be an IE specific issue. I am very new to HTML and JavaScript and would really appreciate any thought and suggestion.

Below is a simple demo code that I mocked up using the author's instruction codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="SliderControl.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2 id="Time slider test"></h2>

        <div id="map" style="height: 600px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>

        <script>
            var map=L.map("map").setView([51.6, -0.09], 10);

            var streetLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                id: '*****',
                accessToken: '*****'
            }).addTo(map);

            var marker1 = L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {time: "2013-01-22 08:42:26+01"});
            var marker2 = L.marker([51.6, -0.09], {time: "2013-01-22 10:00:26+01"});
            var marker3 = L.marker([51.7, -0.09], {time: "2013-01-22 10:03:29+01"});

            var pointA = new L.LatLng(51.8, -0.09);
            var pointB = new L.LatLng(51.9, -0.2);
            var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

            var polyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
                time: "2013-01-22 10:24:59+01",
                color: 'red',
                weight: 3,
                opacity: 1,
                smoothFactor: 1
            });

            layerGroup = L.layerGroup([marker1, marker2, marker3]);
            var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({layer: layerGroup}).addTo(map);
            sliderControl.startSlider();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am seeing the same issue with an opacity slider which uses the jQueryUI slider. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhpqLk4d/11/) to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Further to this, it seems to be related to the version of Leaflet used. I was able to remedy the problem by falling back to Leaflet 0.7, see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dbvfhg6/2/). Not that I really want to go back to 0.7 ...

Comment: FYI: This is actually related to a [bug](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3666) affecting IE11 to do with disabling dragging of the map.